# Python3 - Web Scraper w/ BeautifulSoup, Email Price Alert

Tags: python-3.x, email, beautifulsoup, notifications, python-requests

I'm attempting to setup a script to email me when a phone meets my price and condition threshold on swappa.com. I've gotten to the point when I can email out the latest post that meets my criteria, but I've hit a bit of wall. I need it to only email me when a new post meets my criteria. Currently, it will email me each time the script is ran, whether or not the listing is new.

I'm very new to Python and spent the better part of yesterday and today hobbling together this script, but any insight or information that would help accomplish my goal would be much appreciated!

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
import requests
import smtplib
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText

# define the url in a variable and get the content
page_url = 'https://swappa.com/buy/google-pixel-2-xl-unlocked?sort=date_min'
page_content = requests.get(page_url)

# Put the content into a variable using BeautifulSoup
swappa = BeautifulSoup(page_content.text, 'html.parser')

# Pull text from the h1 tag
phone_name = swappa.h1

# Pull the device details into a list
condition = swappa.find(class_='condition_label')
color = swappa.find(class_='color_label')
storage = swappa.find(class_='storage_label')
price = swappa.find(class_='price')

links = []

for link in swappa.findAll('a', attrs={'href': re.compile("^/listing")}):
    links.append(link.get('href'))


listing_detail = [
    phone_name.contents[0], condition.contents[0], color.contents[0], storage.contents[0],
    '$' + price.contents[1], 'https://swappa.com' + links[0]
    ]


def listing_result():
    if (price.contents[1] <= '420') and (condition.contents[0] == 'Good' or condition.contents[0] == 'Mint'):
        return listing_detail


with open("result.txt", "w+") as result_file:
    result_file.write(str(listing_result()))


with open('result.txt', 'r') as result_file_read:
    result_data = result_file_read.read().replace('\n', '')

if result_data != result_file:
    #  setup sending an email via SMTP
    server = smtplib.SMTP_SSL('smtp.gmail.com', 465)
    server.login("redacted", "redacted")

    # use mime to send email
    msg = MIMEMultipart()

    # setup parameters of the email
    msg['From'] = 'redacted'
    msg['To'] = 'redacted'
    msg['Subject'] = 'Swappa - New Pixel 2 XL Listing'

    # add in the message body
    body = str(listing_result())
    body = MIMEText(body) # convert the body to a MIME compatible string
    msg.attach(body) # attach it to your main message

    # send the email
    server.send_message(msg)
    del msg
```

My idea was to have the latest listing be sent to a text file, then have the contents of that text file saved to a variable so that I could compare it to the text being created. However, I'm at a loss for how to accomplish that.

Comment: The statement `if result_data != result_file:` is checking if a `TextIOWrapper` instance is not equal to an `str` instance, so it will always evaluate to true. You need to come up with a better way to figure out if there is a new listing. I would start by using the value of `listing_result()` just as it is (`str`) and comparing it with what you're reading from `result.txt`(`result_data`).

Comment: @prithajnath I see exactly what you mean, that makes perfect sense. Now the problem I see is that the program will create the text file with the latest listing in there each time it ran. So, I need to figure out how to only write to the file if a listing is new. Thank you for the help, I'll have to think on this one.